# How to know if my file checked this different from TFS file?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

scenario is i have my entire solution checked out in TFS, have a way to retreat only files with differences from files in TFS?

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Get the fitting [PowerTools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) for your TFS and have a close look on the `uu`-Command

`tfpt uu . /noget /recursive`

That will revert the unchanged items and leaves the dirty ones